# Belongs to many association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I guess this is a pretty conceptual question. I'm looking through the possible associations available through Rails, but cannot seem to wrap my head around how to build a "belongs_to_many" and "has_many" association.

Specifically, I want readers to have many books, and each book to belong to many readers.

The closest I can find is the "has_many_and_belongs_to" association, but based on all of the examples I found, it is not exactly accurate.

Likewise, according to the documentation, the "belongs to" and "has many" association is meant as a one to many.

Is there an association available that matches a belongs to many style or some sort of model structure I could use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update: Jul 2022**

`has_and_belongs_to_many` is not recommended anymore.

Please use `has_many :through` approach.

---

You need to use either

1. [`has_and_belongs_to_many`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association)

   ```
    class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_and_belongs_to_many :readers
    end

    class Reader < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_and_belongs_to_many :books
    end
   ```

   with this approach, you will need to create a join table named `books_readers`

   ```
   rails g migration CreateJoinTableBooksReaders books readers
   ```

**OR**

2. [`has_many :through`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association)

   ```
    class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :book_readers
      has_many :readers, through: :book_readers
    end

    class Reader < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :book_readers
      has_many :books, through: :book_readers
    end

    class BookReader < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :reader
      belongs_to :book
    end
   ```

   with this approach, you will need to create a new model `BookReader`

   ```
   rails g model BookReader book:references reader:references
   ```